# Expected onClick event listener to be function but got object type - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, event-listener

I get expected `onClick` event listener to be a function but got object type error. Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Below is my code snippet:

```
render_detail_options = () => {
     return(
         <div>
            <component-name
                name={detail.name}
                recipient={detail.recipient}
            />
        </div>
      );
};
render = () => {
    return (
        <div className="details">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>...</th>
                         </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.state.details.map((detail) => {
                            const option = this.props.options.find(option => option.id === detail.option_id);
                            return (
                                <tr key={detail.id}>
                                     <td>{detail.recipient}</td>
                                     <td>
                                        <some-component>
                                            <button>...</button>
                                            <span onClick={this.render_detail_options(share, model)}>Edit</span>
                                        </some-component>
                                     </td>
                                 </tr>
                           </tbody>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try refactoring it like this, and let me know if it solved your issue.

```
<some-component>
   <button onClick={() => this.render_detail_options(data)}>Edit</button>
</some-component>
```

I would also suggest visiting these [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html). They have everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving the onClick a call back. Try 
`onClick={()=> this.render_detail_options(share, model)}.`